# python histogram printing bin frequency in the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I have a histogram plot. I want to print the frequency of the bins on the plot.

An example is shown here.

[image]

My present code is:

```
df = 
index                      Data
2019-01-09 13:20:17     79.536248
2019-01-09 14:00:17    137.362250
2019-01-09 14:40:17    214.963727
2019-01-09 15:20:17     57.323960
2019-01-09 16:00:17    144.694933
2019-01-09 16:40:17    278.393733
2019-01-10 07:35:22      7.356864
2019-01-10 08:15:17     33.682382
2019-01-10 08:55:17     31.229357
2019-01-10 09:35:17     27.168540
2019-01-10 10:15:17     22.131650
2019-01-10 10:55:17     12.528640
2019-01-10 11:35:17     11.980847

(poa_list, bins, patches)=plt.hist(df['Data'],bins=np.arange(0, 500, 25))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please, share your code entirely, including your DataFrame. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to adapt any of the [annotation examples](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#text-labels-and-annotations) in the Matplotlib Gallery? … [Grouped bar chart with labels](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#grouped-bar-chart-with-labels)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding value labels on a matplotlib bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart) - the bars in a bar chart are patches (matplotlib.patches.Patch
), same for a histogram so this Q&A should suffice.

Comment: @sentence I did add some sample data. Thanks